# How can I use relative paths in proto file import statement?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using the ProtoBufTool custom tool for protobuf-net to generate C# classes from .proto files. I have so far been unable to get the `import` statement in proto files to work with relative paths. The following is my situation:

I have 2 proto files in my project arranged like this:

[image: directory layout]

User.proto:

```
package Models;

message User {
    required int32 ID = 1;
    required string Username = 2;
    // etc...
}
```

UserSearch.proto:

```
package Models.Messages;

import "../User.proto";

message UserSearchRequest {
    optional string Query = 1;
    optional int32 Limit = 2;
    optional int32 Offset = 3;
}

message UserSearchResult {
    required int32 NumResults = 1;
    required int32 NumReturned = 2;
    repeated User Users = 3;
}
```

The User.cs file is generated fine but it fails on the UserSearch file. This is what I see in the Error List window.

- Custom tool error: ../User.proto: File not found.
- Custom tool error: UserSearch.proto: Import "../User.proto" was not found or had errors.
- Custom tool error: UserSearch.proto:22:18: "User" is not defined.

For the record, I have tried using `\\` instead of `/` and I get the same result. Also the import statement works fine if both proto files are in the same directory and I remove the `../`, but this is not how I want to arrange my files.

How can I get relative paths to work in the import statement?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - I must have a bug with the tooling and the paths it uses when talking to `protoc` (google's .proto parser). I will have to look at that and fix it.

More awkward answer; **if** you don't mind using command line tools, you can use google's protoc to compile a .proto to binary, using `--descriptor_set_out={file}`, using whatever `--proto_path` options you choose (so far, this is purely Google tools); you can then pass that compiled descriptor-set into `protogen` as an input (it handles either format).

This would be ok for a scripted build, but you wouldn't want to do it manually! I'll try to look at what is wrong with the tooling. Added to list.

Comment: I would certainly appreciate it if you could fix the bug! Good to know (regarding protogen accepting either format). Maybe I can make use of that. But using the VS tool would be much better for our dev workflow.

Comment: I was having the same problem as Chris, but while using the `protogen.exe` command-line tool. I kept receiving the "Some.proto: File not found." error. Compiling to an intermediate binary file with `protoc` and then feeding that file into `protogen.exe` did the trick.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, this this ever get fixed?